# Interrupt ray execution on exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency, ray

I recently started working with ray for parallel execution. In my serial use case, I have a 'timeout' which stops the execution of my loop. I was wondering how I can do the same using ray.

The way ray currently handles exceptions is that it executes all the runs, collects errors that occurred during the execution and shows the messages in the end.

```
start_time = time.time()

@ray.remote
class Test(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.res = None

    def run(self, c):
        time.sleep(0.25)
        print(c)
        self.res = c
        if time.time()-start_time > 1:
            print('Raise error at %d !' % c)
            raise TimeoutError('Time out.....!!')

    def get_res(self):
        return self.res


test = [Test.remote() for _ in range(num_cpus)]

for i in range(num_cpus*2):
    test[i % num_cpus].run.remote(i)

res = ray.get([t.get_res.remote() for t in test])
```

Is it possible to interrupt ray from executing the next jobs if the current job has timed out? Is there a global way of interrupting the executions?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by **current job**? Ray is a distributed environment, and some/all of the tasks are run **in parallel** (and not sequentially, like if you've run it in regular python loop), so there is no concept of "current job".

In any case, with your code:

```
res = ray.get([t.get_res.remote() for t in test])
```

you're waiting until the last one of your tasks finishes (so there will be no 'res' object  initialized until all tasks finish/fail).

What you can do, is to amend you code a bit, and implement something like this:

```
res = [t.get_res.remote() for t in test]
from ray.exceptions import RayTaskError

while len(res): 
    done_id, res= ray.wait(res)
    try:
        task_res = ray.get(done_id[0])  # debug/explore 'done_id' object to understand the results output (if task finished successfully or not)
    except (RayTaskError, Exception):  
        ray.shutdown()
```